# Matlab Parallel Jobs with Plots

Tags: matlab, plot, parfor

For a very simple but tedious and consuming interface involving a `plot` and a `ginput`, I am requiring some sort of parallelization: while the user decides and selects its input, an image is being loaded and processed.

Since Matlab Parallel Workers with `parfor` `batch` are graphically mute, is there some workaround to make that happens?, without actually opening two different command line instances of Matlab and dealing with the mess after that?

Comment: The batch command is graphically mute, hence, you cannot plot inside them...

Comment: Sorry, read the question too fast. Deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

have you try parfeval function? It provides asynchronous operation in Matlab

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfeval.html

Not ideal solution but it will work.

```
clc
clear
close all
format compact
p = gcp;

I = imread('peppers.png');
f = figure;
[h,w,c] = size(I);
imshow(I);
k = 0;
while true
    [xb,yb,button] = ginput(1);
    if button == 3
        % If mouse right button was clicked brake the loop
        break
    else
        % For other button add job to the cue
        xe = xb+99;
        xe(xe>w) = w;
        ye = yb+99;
        ye(ye>h) = h;
        Imini = I(yb:ye,xb:xe,:);
        filt = fspecial('motion', 50, 45);
        ff(k+1) = parfeval(p,@imfilter,1,Imini,filt);
        k = k +1;
    end

    % Check the cue for finished jobs and get output.
    idx = [];
    for k = 1:length(ff)
        if strcmp(ff(k).State,'finished')
            idx(k) = 1;
            Ifilt = ff(k).OutputArguments{1};
            figure; imshow(Ifilt);
        else
            idx(k) = 0;
        end
    end
    % Remove finished jobs from cue
    idx = logical(idx);
    ff(idx) = [];
    set(0, 'currentfigure', f);
end
```

Better solution could use figure WindowButtonDownFcn method to add job to parfeval cue and WindowButtonMotionFcn to check if cue for finished jobs.

Answer (score 1):

I proposed a [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75420066/does-the-matlab-interface-to-sqlite-support-concurrency/78175386#78175386) to doing something in parallel and then being constrained to a single process. In this case it was a database write. I am less sure on what type of input you need, but this may help you.

**Note** you may need to put some control logic to pause, control figure visibility so as to not overwhelm your user. All of this could be put into a function and executed on `afterEach`.

```
clearvars
close all

% wrap the user input section in a function
f = @(ax) disp(ax.Title.String);
% set up a data que
q = parallel.pool.DataQueue;
% do something after each arrives.
afterEach(q, f);

parfor k = 1 : 10
    name = "My Fig " + num2str(k);
    % loading the figure
    f = figure;
    ax = gca;
    title(ax, name);
    % send back to client for their input
    send(q,ax);
end
```

Comment: Some time has passed, but, I'll check it as soon as I can...