# Does the MATLAB Interface to SQLite support concurrency?

Tags: matlab, sqlite, concurrency

SQLite as a database supports varying degrees of concurrency depending on version and settings, therefore I was expecting the MATLAB Interface to SQLite in the Database Toolbox would support some level of concurrency. And when a database access fails, it should at the very least show errors.

However, when I used the following sniplet,

```
conn=sqlite("sqlite_concurr_test.db","create");
conn.close();
ppool=parpool(4);
ff=parallel.Future.empty();
disp("Write 500 numbers")
for ii=1:500
    ff(ii)=parfeval(ppool,@writeOne,0,ii);
end
for ii=1:500
    ff(ii).wait()
end
delete(ppool);
conn=sqlite("sqlite_concurr_test.db");
readback=conn.sqlread("test");
disp("Readback "+num2str(size(readback,1))+" numbers");

function writeOne(ii)
    conn=sqlite("sqlite_concurr_test.db");
    conn.sqlwrite("test",array2table(ii));
    conn.close();
end
```

I got the unexpected result of

> Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'Processes' profile ...
>
> Connected to the parallel pool (number of workers: 4).
>
> Write 500 numbers
>
> Parallel pool using the 'Processes' profile is shutting down.
>
> Readback 74 numbers

This indicates that some database write did not occur, and there are no error reports.
What can I do to change this behavior? Is there anything I should do to assure parallel access, or at the very least get notifications if anything goes wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that there is no direct solution using MATLAB built-ins for SQLite. It [looks like](https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/doc/begin-concurrent/doc/begin_concurrent.md#:%7E:text=Usually%2C%20SQLite%20allows%20at%20most,system%20still%20serializes%20COMMIT%20commands.) there may be some options if you are comfortable writing your own SQL statements and then using execute your commit.

One possible workaround is [sending the results](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parallel.pool.dataqueue.html) to be written back to the client.

```
conn = sqlite('tst.db','create');
ps = parpool("LocalProfile1",3);
q = parallel.pool.DataQueue;
afterEach(q, @(T) sqlwrite(conn,"myTable",T));

parfor k = 1 : 10000
    T = array2table(rand(1,2));
    send(q,T)
end

Tall = sqlread(conn,"myTable");
assert(height(Tall) == 10000);
```

Comment: I agree that this could help to avoid problems in certain scenarios, but it is more of a helpful workaround for the SQlite problem than a direct solution.

Comment: I expect that there is no direct solution using MATLAB built-ins for SQLite. It [looks like](https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/doc/begin-concurrent/doc/begin_concurrent.md#:~:text=Usually%2C%20SQLite%20allows%20at%20most,system%20still%20serializes%20COMMIT%20commands.) there may be some options if you are comfortable writing your own SQL statements and then using `execute` your commit.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever the configuration of your sqlite3 database connection you can only have one simultaneous writer. With wal mode you can have a single writer running concurrently with multiple reader. In your code sample whatever this statement does `conn.sqlwrite("test",array2table(ii));`, you don't check for returned error if any. So you probably have errors on concurrent writes, but you actully don't detect them.

Comment: Exactly, one would expect returned error/busy-status if any, right? However, as described in the documentation, [sqlwrite](https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/sqlite.sqlwrite.html) has no return value, call back function, status property, or anything else.That's why I'm confused.